# How does nginx return a dynamic URL address

Tags: nginx

```
server {
        listen 6677;

        location /api/tt {
            charset utf-8;
            default_type text/html;

            set $test 0;
            if ($arg_url) {
                set $test 1;
            }

            if ($arg_url ~* "^(?<scheme2>https?)://(?<address>.*)") {
                set $test  "${test}2";
            }

            add_header X-test $test;

            if ($test = 12) {
                return $scheme2://$address;
                # return $arg_url;
            }

            return 400 "<p>error: need url</p>";
        }
}
```

When visiting "http://localhost:6677/api/tt?url=https://google.com" will redirect to "https://google.com"

However, when I use `return $arg_url;`, the text "https://google.com" is returned to me. How can I directly use the `$arg_url` variable to redirect to "https://google.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do a 303 redirect like so:

```
return 303 <URL>;
```